# How to send multiple messages to eventhub using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

I already send batch messages using C# libs. 
I want to do the same thing using python, how to do it?
Actually I'm able to send single messages but batch send will increase my throughtput.
This is the code:

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService

key_name = 'RootManageSharedAccessKey' # SharedAccessKeyName from Azure portal
key_value = '' # SharedAccessKey from Azure portal
sbs = ServiceBusService(service_namespace,
                        shared_access_key_name=key_name,
                        shared_access_key_value=key_value)

sbs.send_event('myhub', '{ "DeviceId":"dev-01", "Temperature":"37.0" }')
```

I think it's possible because on the manual it says:

"The event content is the event message or JSON-encoded string that contains multiple messages."

[Link to the manual](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/servicebus.html?highlight=event%20hub)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace the event content with the format like this,

`[{"Body":"Message1"},{"Body":"Message2"},{"Body":"Message3"}]`

So the complete code will be like this,

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService

key_name = 'RootManageSharedAccessKey' # SharedAccessKeyName from Azure portal
key_value = 'hdckR8xd*********************u5a84RoZSQHE=' # SharedAccessKey from Azure portal
service_namespace = 'myservice-ns' # service bus namespace

sbs = ServiceBusService(service_namespace,
                        shared_access_key_name=key_name,
                        shared_access_key_value=key_value)

sbs.create_event_hub('myhub')

sbs.send_event('myhub', '[{"name":"derek", "gender":"male"},{ "DeviceId":"dev-01", "Temperature":"37.0" }]')
```

Refer to [Event Hubs (classic) REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt652151.aspx) for some information.